# Finding a file in the iPhone sandbox

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, sandbox

At the beginning of my app the user records their voice which is then saved as 'recorded.wav' in the sandbox. How do I later create a string indicating it's location? I would like something that looks like:

```
/var/folders/u6/u6pKbm2MFriwajkdt-OQME+++TI/-Tmp-/recorded.wav
```

Thanks,

Keep in mind this is for the iPhone device and simulator.

Comment: but its relative to your mac(unix) system on which you are working. Why you want path like above one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`NSHomeDirectory()` returns the path to your application's sandbox. You can then reach any file or directory within it.

```
NSString *home = NSHomeDirectory();
NSString *documentsPath = [home stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
```

---

There is also `NSTemporaryDirectory()` which returns the path to the temp folder specific to your app. Do note, that when running your app in the Simulator, `NSTemporaryDirectory()` will return a system-wide directory.

---

If you like a more general solution, lookup the documentation on `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains()` function.

Comment: I was told NSTemporaryDirectory is not good for the iPhone (?)

Comment: @Eric Brotto I haven't had any issues with it in my experience. What is it you have been told about it?

Comment: In any case, if you don't like it, just use `[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tmp"]`. I don't think Apple is going to change the name `tmp` any time soon.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the path to your file via the `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` [foundation function](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html) as such:

```
// Get our document path.
NSArray *searchPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentPath = [searchPaths objectAtIndex:0];

// Get the full path to our file.
NSString *samplePath = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"recorded.wav"];
```

Comment: it's in the tmp not Documents. Does that matter? What would I need to change?

Comment: @Eric To be honest, if you're going to want to keep the file around, I'd be tempted to initially save it into the app's home directory anyway using the above to get the path.

Comment: I don't need to keep the file. In fact it is best that it is destroyed when the app exits (so that it doesn't take up too much memory).

Comment: @Eric To be honest it doesn't matter where it's stored then, although there's no reason *not* to store it in the document directory as above, as long as you delete it when your app exits, or simply overwrite it again on start-up. (Is it at all possible they'd want to keep the same sample - if so it might be nice to give the user the choice on start-up.)